# Selecionar um ID de uma consulta com radiobutton e armazena ele numa sessao

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com dificuldades de pegar uma ID de uma consulta usando array e armazena-lo em uma sessao para usa-lo em outras telas.Qualquer ajuda eu agradeço.Seque o codigo abaixo

[image: Tela do Pedido]

Tela do Pedido

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Projeto Web-ConsultarPedido</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/layoutPrincipal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/formulario.css">
    <style>
  ul{
     list-style: none;
  }
    #lista{
        display:table-cell;
        padding-left:10px;
    }

    p{
     font-family:"arial black";
     font-size:15px;
     margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
      }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>

<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="../_imagens/Logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Cadastra-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php" target="_self">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<section id="form">
    <?php

    session_start();
    $ID_Cliente = $_SESSION['ID_Cliente'];

    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $consulta= "select * from pedido where ClienteID_Cliente='$ID_Cliente'" ;
    $resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível Consultar os seus dados.");
    mysql_close($conexao);



      while($consulta=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $_SESSION["ID_Pedido"]=$consulta["ID_Pedido"];  
        $ID_Pedido = $_SESSION["ID_Pedido"];        
        $Tipo_Servico=$consulta["Tipo_Servico"];
        $Status_Servico=$consulta["Status_Servico"];


          echo "<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Pedidos</legend><input type='radio' name='pedido' value='$ID_Pedido'>
 <p>Tipo de Serviço:$Tipo_Servico<br/>Status_Servico:$Status_Servico<br/></p></input></fieldset>";

      }



     ?>
     <fieldset id="form_field">
        <legend id="form_legend">Opções</legend>
        <ul>
       <li id="lista" > <a href="novopedido.php" id="botao">Novo Pedido</a> </li>
       <li id="lista"> <a href="alterarpedidoform.php" id="botao">Alterar Pedido</a> </li>
       <li id="lista" > <a href="../menucliente.html" id="botao">Excluir Pedido</a> </li>
         <li id="lista" > <a href="../menucliente.html" id="botao">Voltar</a> </li>
        </ul>
     </fieldset>;




</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Tela de Alterar Pedido

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Projeto Web-AlterarPedido</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/layoutPrincipal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/formulario.css">

</head>
<body>

<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="../_imagens/logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Cadastra-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="../login.html" target="_self">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="form">

<?php
   session_start();
    $ID_Pedido = $_SESSION['ID_Pedido'];


    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $consulta= "select * from pedido where ID_Pedido='$ID_Pedido' " ;
    $resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível Consultar os seus dados.");


      while($consulta=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){

        $Tipo_Servico=$consulta["Tipo_Servico"];

      }

?>

    <fieldset id="form_field">
        <legend id="form_legend">Alterar Pedido</legend>
                 <form method="post" action="alterarpedido.php">
                 Tipo de Serviço: <select name="Tipo_Servico"  value="<?php echo $Tipo_Servico;?>">
                 <option name="Reforma Predial">Reforma Predial</option>
                 <option name="Jardinagem">Jardinagem</option>
                 <option name="Eletricista">Eletricista</option>
                   </select> 
                 <fieldset id="form_field">
                      <legend id="form_legend">Opções</legend>
                      <input type="submit" id="botao" value="Alterar">
                      <input type="reset" id="botao" value="Resetar">
                </fieldset>
            </form>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Tela do Banco

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Projeto Web-AlterarPedido</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/layoutPrincipal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/formulario.css">
 </head>
<body>

<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="../_imagens/Logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Cadastra-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="../login.html" target="_self">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<section id="form">
    <?php

    $ID_Pedido=$_POST["ID_Pedido"];
    $Tipo_Servico=$_POST["Tipo_Servico"];




    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $atualiza= "update pedido set Tipo_Servico='$Tipo_Servico' WHERE ID_Pedido='$ID_Pedido'" ;
    mysql_query($atualiza,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível executar a atualização.");
    mysql_close($conexao);



    echo"<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Dados do Pedido</legend>
  <p>Dados do Pedido Alterado com Sucesso !!!</p></fieldset>";



    ?>

<fieldset id="form_field">
     <legend id="form_legend">Opções</legend>
    <a href="../menucliente.html" id="botao">Voltar</a>
</fieldset>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explique-me melhor o que está acontecendo e o que deseja que ocorra... Nao entendi muito bem

Comment: eu fiz uma consulta de Pedido e quero pegar o ID dele e armazenar uma numa sessão.mas não sei como pegar ele selecionando com um radiobutton

Comment: Deixei uma imagem para se ajudar visualizar melhor a duvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar uma requisição ajax para enviar para o servidor o id do pedido que foi clicado. Para não ter que alterar muitas coisas no seu codigo você pode usar a api fetch (disponivel em navegadores mais recentes), em vez de ter que usar o plugin jquery.

Basicamente você deve adicionar o seguinte bloco de javascript antes do fechamento da tag **body** do arquivo Tela do pedido:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //retorna um vetor com todos os radio buttons com name igual a pedido
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('pedido');

    //percorre o array de radio button adicionando um evento para quando houver um click 
    //em um deles
    for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){

        radios[i].onclick = function(){
            //quando um radio button for clicado, envia o id dele par ao servidor
            enviarPedidoId(this.value);
        };
    }
    function enviarPedidoId(id_pedido){
        var parametros = { 
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'id_pedido=' + id_pedido,
        headers: new Headers({
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }) 
        };

        //pagina em php para receber o id do pedido e armazenar na sessao
        fetch('recebePedido.php', parametros)
        .then(function(response) {

        }); 
    }
</script>
```

E crie um novo arquivo em php (para não mexer no que esta feito). No exemplo acima foi criado um arquivo chamado recebePedido.php, com o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['id_pedido'] = $_POST['id_pedido'];
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado serviu direitinho